# Large dataset clip (in visualization) API Javascript ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm working on a project in which I need to integrates features from our ArcGIS server and display them in a mobile application. Using the ArcGIS API for Javascript I'm having issues to understand if what I want is possible, I'm pretty new to Javascript so maybe I didn't find the solution by reading the guidance provided for developers (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/quick-start/)

Basically, I have these elements to display in a map:

1. A small point or polygon feature (and this is not an issue)
2. a MultiPolygon feature that actually is quite big and I have some issues in visualization since it's very slow.

I wonder if there is a way to 'clip' the MultiPolygon feature according to the extent of the 1st element.

I read about:

- Spatial query and query by attributes: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-Query.html
- Query a feature layer: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/query-a-feature-layer/
- Filter feature layer: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/filter-a-feature-layer/

But I think no one of these it's good for my case since the large MultiPolygon features don't contain (and I can't add) an attribute useful to filter the data properly.

I 'just' need a kind of clip by extent but only in the user visualization (according to the extent of the 1st features), is there a way to do it? Someone can point me to the right thing to use or a workaround?

P.s. I need to it on the server side, and not on client-side.

Comment: you are getting the multipolygon from a service or you have it on the client? .. you just want to visualize it or you need to do something else on the client?

Comment: The Multipolygon is a Feature service we host on our portal (shared only internally). Clients just need to visualize it. 
We thought another option could  also be publish a WMTS in our portal and share it with the clients, but as i read from here (https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/publish-tiles.htm)  the feature layer hosted nneds to be public.